# How to protect this circuit from shorting out / reverse polarity?

Tags: mosfet, protection, reverse-polarity

I'm building a device that uses **multiple** TRS jacks for power and communication. (I know that audio jack is not the best choice for power but it's important for overall design and I really want to make it work with those connectors). When the cable carrying power is plugged-in the device might already by powered from another socket. Every socket can be a power source as well as sink.

I'm aware that why being plugged in the tip of the jack will also temporarily connect with sleeve socket connector. I'm looking for a way to protect the circuit and allow it to keep working while plugging and unplugging the jacks.

I'm considering the following options:

**zener diode on a ground connection** (but I'm worried about the power loss on the diode, as the device is battery powered)
[image: zener diode on ground pin]

**something MOSFET based** (but not this...)
[image]

VIN connects the input to LN2266 step-up switching regulator.

Comment: So, you are swallowing a spider to catch the fly? You probably know where this song ends.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You have a basic connector problem that you don't want to fix so, instead of fixing that properly, you are trying to fix it by adding something else. This might spiral out of control like the song I mentioned.

Comment: 1) to protect agains reversed polarity, I suggest that you use a circuit like shown here: https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/simulate-mosfet-based-ideal-diode Note that you don't actually need this, with a jack plug it is not possible to reverse the polarity unless you use a jack that has its polarity reversed. 2) Short circuit protection is a good thing but it needs to be in the **supply** not in your input / your circuit. 3) I agree with Andy that this connector isn't designed for this purpose and you using it like that anyway is asking for trouble.

Comment: What you do to the device makes little to no difference, as plugging in the connector still shorts out the power supply. Protecting the device battery from a short circuit at the connector is easy. If the device has also other connections to outside world, you must also think what happens if the power supply positive tip contacts the grounded sleeve, if your supplies and other devices are all ground-referenced and you have a 1A power supply, you'll have 1A flowing via other wires and devices which may not handle it.

Comment: I guess, that even if I manage to protect the power supply from being damaged by the source there is no way to keep the device working while any of those are shorted. I guess the audio jacks are really no-go :)

Comment: What sort of voltages/current is your power?  What is the average and peak current draw of the device's circuitry?  Is the signal analog or digital, and what sort of current levels?  For general purpose power in/out, all of the above objections apply, but if your circuit and signal consumption is very low I can think of a few ideas that might work.